# CSS with a 2 gradient button?

Tags: html, css

Below is an image of a button we use on our site, it's a .png.

We'd like to see if we can get really close to it with CSS on a standard button.

The gradient goes top: #E14C5B to middle: #D33742 to bottom: #B61C27 with a couple pixel radial of round corners.

Is that even possible in CSS?

[image]

Comment: yes it is, try this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: CSS3 Gradients are your friend.  Colorzilla, the link @jackJoe linked to is what I use all the time.  It's a great tool.

Comment: Personally I don't like some of the new CSS3 options, one of them is gradient. It just doesn't show it right. I'd make a div and make this button's image the background-image.

Comment: @OriShuss what do you mean it doesn't show right?

Comment: I mean that if you make the same gradient twice, once with css and once with photoshop, the one in photoshop looks better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get ya started...

**HTML**

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

**CSS with some background gradients**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One);
button {
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#E14C5B), color-stop(0.5, #D33742), to(#B61C27));
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/ZPaYv/1/embedded/result/)**

**Screenshot:**

[image: Button]

If you want some kind of clicky feedback type look on click, you could also add:

```
button:active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**[DEMO w/ `:active`](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/ZPaYv/2/)**

This is only prefixed for `-webkit` browsers. You'll need to provide the proper vendor prefixes for whatever you are supporting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cross-browser version using css gradient.
I specified 4 colors for the gradient.
The first gradient from 0 to 50% and the second gradient from 51% to 100%.

Ex.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f64757 0%,#f83b49 50%,#eb2735 51%,#ce0011 100%);
```

[image: Button using css gradient only]

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WcWgd/)

Please note that the red i took are brighter than in tour example.
Just play with the css to adjust colors that fit your needs.